# C++ How to delete a specific row or column in a dynamically allocated 2d array?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

So, I dynamically allocated a 2d array in this way:

```
int rs, co;
cin >> ro;
cin >> co;

int **array = new int* [ro];

for(int i = 0; i < ro; i++){
    array[i] = new int [co];
}
```

I filled it:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ro; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < co; j++){
        cout << "Row: " << i << " Column: " << j << "  : ";
        cin >> *(*(array + i) + j);
    }
}
```

My question is:
how can I deallocate an X row or column where X is given by the user?
I know I should use "delete" command but I can not understand how

Comment: You can delete a row but not a column. What is your goal here? I ask because I think this is likely the wrong approach.

Comment: If you want to remove a column create a new array with out that column.

Comment: my exercise requires to dinamically allocate a 2d arrays and then delete a row or a column
I thought to deallocate each single elements of a given column but i don't how

Comment: You may need to create a new smaller matrix and copy instead. Well at least in the case of deleting a column.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "delete." Does your assignment define what that means? Does it mean to act as if the given row or column doesn't exist (and how, should you make an entirely new 2d array, or just pretend the extra memory doesn't exist)?

Comment: Actually no… the text it's unclear.
But I suppose to act as if the given row or column doesn't exist, not fill a row or column with 0 or create another array

Comment: This question seems pretty clear to me. I don't know why you would think it isn't

Answer (score 6):

**You cannot delete a column, but you can delete a row.**

If this doesn't make sense to you directly, try reading my [2D dynamic array (C)](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/2d-dynamic-array-c/). Focus on the figure:

[image]

I know that my link is in C, but what you try to do reminds me of C. In C++, you could use an [`std::vector<int>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) instead.

---

I assume that you know that you can write:

```
array[i][j]
```

instead of:

```
*(*(array + i) + j)
```

---

Example on deleting first row on a matrix with two rows.

```
delete [] array[0];
int **tmp = new int*[1];
tmp[0] = array[1];
delete [] array;
array = tmp;
```

---

Generalized example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    int ro = 3, co = 2;
    int **array = new int* [ro];

    for(int i = 0; i < ro; i++){
        array[i] = new int [co];
    }
    // fill and print the matrix
    for(int i = 0; i < ro; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < co; j++) {
            array[i][j] = i;
            cout << array[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    int rowToDel = 1;
    delete [] array[rowToDel];
    int **tmp = new int*[ro - 1];
    int tmpI = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < ro; ++i)
        if(i != rowToDel)
            tmp[tmpI++] = array[i];
    delete [] array;
    array = tmp;
    ro = ro - 1;

    cout << "Array after deleting " << rowToDel << "-th row\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < ro; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < co; j++) {
            cout << array[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0 0 
1 1 
2 2 
Array after deleting 1-th row
0 0 
2 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can delete a row by simply calling

```
delete [] array[i];
```

You cannot delete columns, since columns are not lined up like rows are. 
For example, lets say we have a 2D array like this:

```
row1: abcd
row2: efgh
row3: ijkl
```

In the computer, the data is actually lined up like this:

```
abcd   .... other data.... efgh .... other data..... ijkl
```

Deleting a row is easy, since the computer has them lined up next to eachother. But, because the rows are created dynamically, they do NOT have to reside next to eachother. They are allocated wherever there is space is available.

So, the columns are not lined up at all, and it doesn't make sense to "deallocate".

Comment: got it, thanks. But It makes me create a doubt: there is a way to create a 2d array without a pointer of pointer?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

Comment: Note that deleting a row as is demonstrated in this answer will leave an invalid pointer in the outer array for you to trip over. The subsequent rows should be moved up one slot to fill in the gap.

Answer (score 2):

With a 2D array of vector is easy.
Just use erase function for rows.
For columns, iterate on rows and delete each element:

```
int ro = 4, co = 3;
vector< vector<int> > vec(ro);
for (int i = 0; i < ro; i++)
    vec[i].resize(co);

// fill and print the matrix
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < vec[i].size(); j++) {
        vec[i][j] = i;
        cout <<vec[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int rowErasePosition = 1;

vec.erase(vec.begin() + rowErasePosition);

// reprinting
cout << "second row deleted" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < vec[i].size(); j++) {
        cout << vec[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

//deleting column
int columnErasePosition = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
    vec[i].erase(vec[i].begin() + columnErasePosition);
}

// reprinting
cout << "second column deleted" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < vec[i].size(); j++) {
        cout << vec[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```